# error: expected primary-expression before ',' token edit status 1

Tags: error

Im using tinkercad for my robotics class and I can't seem to figure out a solution for this problem.
Heres my codes:

```
#include <LiquidCrystal.h> //LCD library
#define echo 2
#define trig 3

// Gas Sensor
#define GREEN 4
#define Yellow 6
#define RED 7
#define Buzzer 5
#define Sensor A0

float duration;
float distance;

LiquidCrystal lcd(13,,12,11,10,9,8);

int sensor_Input;
float temp;

void setup()
{
  // Ultrasonic sensor
  pinMode(trig, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(echo, INPUT);
  Serial.begin(9600);
  lcd.begin(13, 2);
  
  //temp
  measure_Temp();
  display_Temp();
  
  // Gas Sensor
  for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
    pinMode(i, OUTPUT);
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop()
{
  // Ultrasonic Sensor
  time_Measurement();
  distance = duration * (0.0343) /2;
  
  display_distance();
  
  // Gas Sensor
  for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
    digitalWrite(i, LOW);
  
  status_Indicator();
}

void status_Indicator()
{
  // Gas Sensor
  int sensor_In = analogRead(A0);
  Serial.println(sensor_In);
  
  if ( sensor_In>=40 )
  {
    digitalWrite(RED, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(Buzzer, HIGH);
  }
  else if (sensor_In >=25 )
  {
    digitalWrite(Yellow, HIGH);
  }
  else 
  {
    digitalWrite(GREEN, HIGH);
  }
  delay(10);
}

void time_Measurement()
{
  // Ultrasonic Sensor
  digitalWrite(trig, LOW);
  delayMicroseconds(2);
  
  digitalWrite(trig, HIGH);
  delayMicroseconds(10);
  digitalWrite(trig, LOW);
  
  duration = pulseIn(echo, HIGH);
}

void display_distance()
{
  lcd.clear();
    lcd.setCursor(0, 0);
  Serial.print("Distance in m: ");
  Serial.print(distance);
  Serial.println();
  lcd.print("distance in m: ");
  lcd.setCursor(5, 1);
  lcd.print(distance);
  delay(1000);
}



void measure_Temp()
{
  //Temp
  sensor_Input = analogRead(A0);
  temp = (float)sensor_Input / 1024;
  temp = temp *5;
  temp = temp - 0.5;
  temp = temp *100;
}

void display_Temp()
{
  //temp
  lcd.setCursor(0, 0);
  Serial.print("Temp. in Celcius: ");
  Serial.print(temp);
  Serial.println();
  lcd.print("Temp. in Celcius: ");
  lcd.setCursor(5, 1);
  lcd.print(temp);
  delay(500);
}
```

Comment: @ user77041 Please provide the full error output.

Answer (score 2):

You have two commas in the command when making the `lcd` object:

```cpp
LiquidCrystal lcd(13,,12,11,10,9,8);
```

Probably just a typo, delete the comma and you should be good to go.

```cpp
LiquidCrystal lcd(13,12,11,10,9,8);
```